# Zabbix API import, no response

Tags: python, api, zabbix

I have problem with import two templates to zabbix, I just export whole data, but I can't reupload 2 templates. Zabbix do not sent any response.
I'm using Zabbix 3.4, python(requests) and jSON format, for the rest objects (groups, hosts, etc.) everything works fine. (I used postman to confirm empty response)

Is is possible that the objects are too big? jSONs have 113313 and 165888 characters, but for object which has 120294 works correct.

What can I do to get response?

PS. same problem with xml format

Comment: Even if the answer is empty, you should get an http return code. It's more likely a apache or nginx issue, check the webserver logs in real time